# Toggling Login and User Titles

Tags: html, css, authentication, login-control, login-script

On a webpage that uses a login system its always on the navbar right? Well I am wondering how to make it, after logging in, change from "Login" to the person's Username. 
Ex.

New Person Entering Website Sees this Navbar:

---

```
Home  Forum   Store   Login
```

---

Existing User with signed in account sees this:

---

```
Home  Forum   Store   Welcome [User]
```

---

If you have some input that would be great.

Once again I am just trying to figure out the toggle between them.

Response to comments:

Code Languages: Html, PhP, Css

This is the current code I have to get the login name

```
<?= $fgmembersite->UserFullName(); ?>
```

The fgmembersite refers to a css script.

Comment: Check if user is logged in, store it in session variable, and add one condition (if logged in -> show welcome [user], if not -> show regular menu) in your menu code - general answer.

Comment: At this point it's impossible to help you with the information you give us. Please provide some more information first.
What server side language are you using? How does your code look like? What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a login script working, then check if is set any of sessions and use one of the values set in your database... For example :

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
    Home  Forum   Store   Welcome [User]
    <?php
}
    else{ ?>
    Home  Forum   Store   Login
    }
    ?>
```

EDIT: If your question is to know how to show the username of the currently logged user, you can do it like this:

```
Home  Forum   Store   Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username']); ?>
```

this will show the 'username' of the user which is logged in.

Comment: @Devin - Hope it helps ;)